# Endpoint monitoring of Web App using Azure Traffic Manager

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager

I have a WebApp in Azure, which has incoming certificate enabled in place. Is it possible to check the endpoint of the API hosted in the WebApp through Traffic Manager probe? I cannot find a solution to probe the endpoint from there since it returns 403 "Error 403 - Forbidden: Client Certificate Required."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to validate the client certificate via Traffic Manager probe referring to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-faqs#can-i-monitor-https-endpoints). Traffic Manager supports probing over HTTPS. But please note that Traffic manager cannot provide any certificate validation, including:

> - Server-side certificates are not validated
> - SNI server-side certificates are not validated
> - Client certificates are not supported

Comment: If the reply answers your question, do you mind accepting it?

Comment: Can you provide any alternative on how to do the same using any other service which Azure provides? We are using Traffic Manager on top of the Web App for load balancing.

Comment: May I know why you are using a traffic manager which works at the DNS level? If it's not a must, you may consider a 7-layer load balancer- Azure application gateway [supportting end to end SSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ssl-overview).

Answer (score 0):

For HTTP or HTTPS monitoring protocol, a common practice on the endpoint side is to implement a custom page within your application - for example, /health.aspx. Using this path for monitoring, you can perform application-specific checks, such as checking performance counters or verifying database availability. Based on these custom checks, the page returns an appropriate HTTP status code.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-monitoring

Comment: We have a custom html page added in the webapp, but as I mentioned, Incoming Certificate is enabled for the WebApp, so the probe fails with 403 "Forbidden: Client Certificate Required." error.